# Duals of free modules are isomorphic implies modules are isomorphic

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

If F and G are free modules, and if F dual is isomorphic to G dual, does that imply that F is isomorphic to G? 
By dual of a module H I mean Hom(H,R) where H is an R module.

Comment: For finitely generated modules, yes.

Comment: Yes, in general?

Comment: When speaking about duals in commutative algebra, one should say which kind of duals one talks about. The naive analog of the 'vector space'-dual, i.e. $\operatorname{Hom}_R(-,R)$, is rarely used and thus not the only notion of a dual module.

Comment: Oh, yes I mean dual in the sense of dual of a vector space, I.e. Hom(F,R) where F is an R module